# how do i keep two div's side by side when one is fixed size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to keep two div's side by side, regardless of the container width when one has a fixed size. Here is my sample html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="date">
        <div class="month">APR</div>
        <div class="day">6</div>
        <div class="weekday">Mon</div>
      </div>
      <div class="details">
        <p>Kickstarter sustainable readymade Neutra viral, crucifix PBR. Migas tote bag art party, narwhal flannel hashtag YOLO XOXO polaroid. Ennui iPhone pour-over kitsch, lumbersexual stumptown gastropub flexitarian. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is my sample css

```
  .date{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 4em;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#fff,#fff 1em,#e7e7e7);
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  .month{
      background-color: blue;
      color: white;
      border-top-left-radius: 5px;
      border-top-right-radius:5px;
      padding: 2px 0 2px 0;
    }
  .day{
      font-size: 2em;
    }
  .details{
      width:100% - 5em;
      padding: 5px;
      border-radius: 6.5px;
      background-color: white;
      border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
    }
    .item{
        border-radius: 6.5px;
        margin: 5px;
        padding: 5px;
        display: block;
        border: 0;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(242, 242, 242), rgb(242, 242, 242) 1em, rgb(255, 255, 255));
    }
```

I am using bootstrap and I don't want to use tables to make this happen. The left hand side is fixed width of 4em and the right should fill up the rest of the width. I have been toying around with this for a while and thought maybe stack over flow crowd could point me in the right direction.

[here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hC1fkFgdwC9bgh2OxZTy?p=preview)

Comment: how about using float?

Comment: sidenote: `width:100% - 5em;` should be `width:calc(100% - 5em); `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just float the date container to the left, and add a margin to `.details`:

```
.date{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 4em;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#fff,#fff 1em,#e7e7e7);
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: left;
}
```

And similarly:

```
.details{
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 6.5px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
    margin-left: 5em;
}
```

Notice that there is no requirement for a `width` property of `.details` using this method.

[**Updated Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Jh6MwawPklkagBHvPg8u?p=preview)

Answer (score 3):

You could set the display property for your date and details divs to table-cell:

```
.date,.details {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

**[bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/dYHq4beYwo)**

Answer (score 2):

You can just `float:left` the `.date` div and apply a `margin-left:4em` or more to the `.details` div.

**DEMO**

http://plnkr.co/edit/V45nM6qPSuIclCvVDQe0?p=preview

Comment: Please upvote answers that already exist, rather than duplicating them.

Comment: I was in the middle of editing his plunker when you guys posted it :)

Comment: Matter of seconds really :)